# How to change the datetime format for categorized in period

Tags: r, datetime

I need your help to solve my problem with the datetime in R.

I have a datetime in a factor class, like :

```
"02/02/2010 12:00" "02/02/2010 12:05" "02/02/2010 12:10"
```

Then i just want to pick the time, like : `"12:00" "12:05" "12:10"`

I have tried to convert first, the factor to character before i changed it to date class. My goal is want to classified the range of time as the periode (evening, noon, afternoon, night)

```
getPeriode <- function(RAYON) {
    Midi <- as.character.POSIXt("12:00", format ='%H:%M:%S') # Winter Solstice

    d <- as.character.POSIXt(HEURE, format='%H:%M:%S')

    ifelse (rayon < 10, "night",
            ifelse (d = Midi, "noon",
                ifelse (d >= Midi, "afternoon", "evening")))

}
```

But, it seems not working.. :(

I guess the key is when we want to input the data in

```
d <- as.character.POSIXt(HEURE, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

I realy appreciate your help.. THanks Before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find operations on date and time classes rather confusing, and in this case I think it would be easier to to work with your variables as strings and integers. I'm not sure I understood all of your code, but this might inspire a solution of your own.

```
datetime <- c("02/02/2010 07:00", "02/02/2010 08:05", "02/02/2010 11:00",
              "02/02/2010 12:10", "02/02/2010 16:10", "02/02/2010 23:10")
heure <- as.integer(substr(datetime, 12, 13))
conversion <- data.frame(datetime=datetime, heure=heure,
     period=cut(heure, c(-Inf, 7, 10, 12, 17, Inf),
                labels=c("night", "morning", "noon", "afternoon", "evening")))
```

Giving you

```
> conversion
          datetime heure    period
1 02/02/2010 07:00     7     night
2 02/02/2010 08:05     8   morning
3 02/02/2010 11:00    11      noon
4 02/02/2010 12:10    12      noon
5 02/02/2010 16:10    16 afternoon
6 02/02/2010 23:10    23   evening
```

Comment: Instead of using a `substr` you could also just format it as an hour. `dates=as.POSIXlt(dates,format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')` followed by `heure=as.numeric(format(dates, '%H'))` would work.

Comment: @Backlin : Thanks a lot for your answer, that give me an idea for the solution.. :)


nograpes : Yes, you are right, its works to with your method.. Thanks..